# std::mdspan stride layout policy

Tags: c++, c++23, mdspan

I'd like to understand how the `std::layout_stride` policy for the `std::mdspan` works. At this point, no compiler supports this new C++23 library type, although a reference implementation exists: https://github.com/kokkos/mdspan. However, I could not find a good explanation on this layout type either on the github wiki ([A Gentle Introduction to mdspan](https://github.com/kokkos/mdspan/wiki/A-Gentle-Introduction-to-mdspan)) or the [P0009r18](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p0009r18.html) paper.

The following program, using `std::layout_right` (the default) for an `mdspan` prints

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

```
std::vector v {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30};
std::mdspan<int, 
            std::extents<size_t, 2, 3>,
            std::layout_right> mv{v.data()};
for (std::size_t r = 0; r < mv.extent(0); r++)
{
  for (std::size_t c = 0; c < mv.extent(1); c++)
  {
     std::cout << mv[r, c] << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

If we change to `std::layout_left`, the output becomes:

```
1 3 5
2 4 6
```

```
std::mdspan<int, 
            std::extents<size_t, 2, 3>,
            std::layout_left> mv{v.data()};
```

My understanding is that `std::layout_stride` can control the stride. For instance, jumping every 2 elements (from the underlying sequence) for rows and 3 elements for columns. However, I did not find any example on this matter. Does anyone have examples showing how this really works?

It can be experimented on godbolt here: https://godbolt.org/z/Mxa7cej1a.

**UPDATE**

Based on the answer from @KamilCuc, I deduce the following:

```
    stdex::mdspan<int, 
                  stdex::extents<size_t, stdex::dynamic_extent, stdex::dynamic_extent>, 
                  stdex::layout_stride> 
    mv{ v.data(), 
       { stdex::dextents<size_t,2>{2, 3}, 
         std::array<std::size_t, 2>{3, 1}}};
```

result:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

This is the equivalent of `layout_right`.

stride: `std::array<std::size_t, 2>{1, 1}`

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
```

stride: `std::array<std::size_t, 2>{3, 2}`

```
1 3 5
4 6 8
```

stride: `std::array<std::size_t, 2>{9, 3}`

```
 1  4  7
10 13 16
```

Comment: https://github.com/kokkos/mdspan/blob/cf374bc4150f2194024fce187fc27943223de15b/tests/test_layout_stride.cpp https://github.com/kokkos/mdspan/blob/a9489aecd1ff61a2464f62dc25e79ca754b4b0fd/include/experimental/__p0009_bits/layout_stride.hpp#L68 https://github.com/kokkos/mdspan/blob/973ef6415a6396e5f0a55cb4c99afd1d1d541681/compilation_tests/ctest_constexpr_layouts.cpp#L27 overall https://github.com/kokkos/mdspan/search?p=2&q=layout_stride

Comment: Thanks. I've seen the first two, I missed the last one. There was one example there that I can learn from.

Comment: Please post the update as an answer instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Answer inspired by OP's update which in turn was inspired by @KamilCuc's comment:

Using CTAD* one can nicely create an `mdspan` with `layout_stride` like this:

```cpp
std::dextents<std::size_t, 2> shape{2, 3};
std::array<std::size_t, 2> strides{shape.extent(1), 1};

std::mdspan mv{v.data(), std::layout_stride::mapping{shape, strides}};
```

These particular `strides` just result in the same mapping as `layout_right`. I refer back to OP's update for further examples of different strides.

CTAD will cause `mdspan` to infer the data type from `v.data()`, and both the `extents` (including index type) and the layout from the mapping passed as the second argument to the constructor. In this example CTAD is also used to deduce the `extents` template argument of `layout_stride::mapping`. One could go even further with CTAD like here:

```cpp
std::extents shape{std::size_t{2}, std::size_t{3}};
std::array strides{shape.extent(1), std::size_t{1}};
```

Note that one cannot use `dextents` with CTAD which makes sense as they are there as a shortcut when not using CTAD and writing `dextents` with CTAD would actually be longer than writing `extents`. The resulting `extents` type is the same.

---

*Class Template Argument Deduction